# Dreamweaver cc SQL Query

Tags: sql, image

I know this question have been asked many times before and I have searched and tried figure out where I am going wrong and I can't seem to do it.

Any help would be apreciated.  Thanks in advance.

I have a dreamweaver cc Update query already set up and it works great.  I want to now add an image to my database.

Here is my query:

```
    $image = $_FILES['speakerimage']['tmp_name'];
    $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE Speakers SET speaker=%s,     chkSportsCeleb=%s, chkEntertainment=%s, chkEmcee=%s, chkCFLAA=%s, chkKeynote=%s, chkAutioneer=%s, speakerImg=%s WHERE speakerID=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['speaker'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['SportsCeleb']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['Entertainment']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['Emcee']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['CFLAA']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['Keynote']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['Autioneer']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   $imgContent,
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['speakerID'], "int"));
```

When I preview my code in the browser this is what I  get:

```
   query = UPDATE Speakers SET speaker='John Doe', chkSportsCeleb=1, chkEntertainment=0, chkEmcee=0, chkCFLAA=1, chkKeynote=1, chkAutioneer=0, speakerImg= WHERE speakerID=59  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE speakerID=59' at line 1
```

I believe the image content should show up as gibberish.  I just can't figure out how to re-write this.

Thanks

Roland

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using a MySql 5.7 for my database

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image into a variable and then directly specifying it in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
$image = $_FILES['speakerimage']['tmp_name'];
$imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE Speakers SET speaker=%s,     chkSportsCeleb=%s, chkEntertainment=%s, chkEmcee=%s, chkCFLAA=%s, chkKeynote=%s, chkAutioneer=%s, $imgContent WHERE speakerID=%s",
// ...
```

Comment: @RolandWinowich OK, but your code is not using a prepared statement and therefore is not ideal.  We should find a way to bind an image blob to a PHP prepared statement.

Comment: I decided to set up a test db and simply add an image to the db.  My db consists of an ID, Int(10),  and Image, blob.  I uploaded the same image to each db. I was abel to update an image with the following MySql Update statement. Then I get the image back and display it.  I checked my db and in my Image field it shows [BLOB - 22.2KiB].

Comment: Once I had it working I added an Image field in my db, Blob, I change the db info, commented out the old db fields etc.  I ran it and it I got the message below  "File uploaded successfully."  But the image was not displayed.  I went to my db and the image was added but it shows as follows [BLOB - 0B].

Any thoughts as to why it would not be saving the image properly? See second post for script.

Comment: // $insert = $db->query("update test_image set image = '$imgContent' where id=2");
        $insert = $db->query("update Speakers set speakerImg = '$imgContent' where speakerID=59");
        if($insert){
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
    
        //Check connection
        if($db->connect_error){
          die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

Comment: //Get image
           //$result = $db->query("SELECT speakerImg FROM Speakers WHERE   speakerID=59");
       // $result = $db->query("SELECT image FROM test_image WHERE id=1");
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();
         //Render image
        header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
        echo $imgData['img']; 
        }else{
            echo 'Image not found...';
        }
            }else{
                echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
       }else{
            echo "Please select an image file to upload.";